# Postgresql lowercase to compare data

Tags: postgresql, lowercase

I want to get the contents from a row in the Postgresql database and compare the lowercase version of it to a lowercase version of a user input to check if it exists in the database.

i tried:

```
"SELECT LOWER(name) FROM user_names WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name ASC"
```

but that make query not working at all.

**EDIT**

I am trying to implement an autocomplete Jquery UI like here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote
for search box (for names)

using javascript and php.

**php code:**

```
$search = ($_GET['term']);
       if (!$con)
        { die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error ());}

       else
        {

        $sql = "SELECT name FROM users_table WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name ASC";
        $result = pg_query($sql);
        $json = '[';
        $first = true;
        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
        {

        if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['name'].'"}';
    }
    $json .= ']';
    echo $json;

    exit();

    }
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#auto').autocomplete(
        {
            source: "./file.php",
            minLength: 3

        })

})
```

all above work great.. exactly like in Demo here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

my problem is that the names in database stored in Uppercase (e.g. LORI)
and of course the user prefers to insert a lowercase in search box to search for name (e.g. lori). but since it stored in uppercase, i need to convert it.

i tried as your suggestion :

```
$sql = "SELECT LOWER(name) FROM users_table WHERE name ILIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

then i got an empty drop down list!
pretty weird!

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set name to lower in the where statement not the select `LOWER(name) `

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=postgresql+like+case-insensitive):

```
SELECT LOWER(name) FROM user_names 
WHERE name ILIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: thanks but still i got an empty array from JSON if i use LOWER

Comment: @Shadin Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my post. The suggestion is to change `LIKE` to `ILIKE`

Comment: yes i noticed that and tried it. i do not undersatnd why i got an empty array

Comment: It works here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f6f97/3 can you post more details about your schema? The language you're using? The problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm sorry @Shadin, I just can't see anything wrong here. I've created my own page using the code you posted and it's working fine. Here's the code I used, maybe this can help you https://gist.github.com/2554894

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH dwurf !! it works when i removed 'lower' and just use ILIKE !! i really appreciate your help\1